# Intermittent errors using lighttpd + mod_proxy

Tags: lighttpd, mod-proxy

I'm running lighttpd v1.4.18 on an embedded linux device. Lighty is listening on port 80 and serves as a reverse proxy so that _http://192.168.0.1/foo1 requests are proxied to _http://127.0.0.1:11111

```
### 1st appreach
proxy.server = ( "^/foo1" => ( "" => ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 11111 )))

### 2nd approach
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/foo1" { 
    proxy.server = ( "" => (( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 11111 ))) 
}
```

Basically, this works fine. But I do encounter 404 errors on a random basis, especially after startup. If the background service "foo1" isn't be running I get a 503 error message, which makes sense. But since I can query _http://192.168.0.1:11111 thats not the case... The device is up and running an "foo1" is ready to serve incoming requests. So, why do these 404 errors crop up using either 1st of 2nd approach?!

This is what the log reveals...

```
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (request.c.294) fd: 6 request-len: 164 
POST /foo1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.1
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.7
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 450
Connection: close
SOAPAction: ""


2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.205) -- splitting Request-URI 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.206) Request-URI  :  /foo1
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.207) URI-scheme   :  http 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.208) URI-authority:  192.168.0.1 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.209) URI-path     :  /foo1
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.210) URI-query    :   
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.260) -- sanatising URI 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.261) URI-path     :  /foo1
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (mod_proxy.c.1080) proxy - start 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.375) -- before doc_root 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.376) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.377) Rel-Path     : /foo1
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.378) Path         :  
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.426) -- after doc_root 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.427) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.428) Rel-Path     : /foo1
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.429) Path         : /var/www/foo1
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.446) -- logical -> physical 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.447) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.448) Rel-Path     : /foo1
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.449) Path         : /var/www/foo1
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.466) -- handling physical path 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.467) Path         : /var/www/foo1
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.523) -- file not found 
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.524) Path         : /var/www/foo1
2012-03-05 08:31:36: (response.c.114) Response-Header: 
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 345
Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2012 07:31:36 GMT
Server: lighttpd
```

And this is what I expect to see...

```
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (request.c.294) fd: 6 request-len: 164 
POST /foo1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.1
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.7
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 450
Connection: close
SOAPAction: ""


2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.205) -- splitting Request-URI 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.206) Request-URI  :  /foo1 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.207) URI-scheme   :  http 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.208) URI-authority:  192.168.0.1
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.209) URI-path     :  /foo1 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.210) URI-query    :   
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.260) -- sanatising URI 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.261) URI-path     :  /foo1 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.1080) proxy - start 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.1116) proxy - ext found 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.1159) proxy - used fair balancing 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.1240) proxy - found a host 127.0.0.1 11111 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.375) -- before doc_root 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.376) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.377) Rel-Path     : /foo1 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.378) Path         :  
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.426) -- after doc_root 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.427) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.428) Rel-Path     : /foo1 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.429) Path         : /var/www/foo1 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.446) -- logical -> physical 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.447) Doc-Root     : /var/www 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.448) Rel-Path     : /foo1 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.449) Path         : /var/www/foo1 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.377) connect delayed: 7 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.994) proxy: fdevent-out 1 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.805) proxy - connect - delayed success 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.961) proxy: fdevent-in 4 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.645) proxy - have to read: 607 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.961) proxy: fdevent-in 4 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (mod_proxy.c.645) proxy - have to read: 0 
2012-03-05 08:42:43: (response.c.114) Response-Header: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Server: gSOAP/2.7
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 490
Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2012 07:42:43 GMT
```

Would a newer version fix that problem? Any other suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems as if the lighty is unable to handle the situation where the backgroud service "foo1" may be stoppen and started again. If lighty is configured to revers proxy to foo1 wihich is temporarily not available, then the probelm appears.does

Answer (score 0):

mod_proxy in lighttpd has many bugs and isn't all that reliable (things like a large mismatch in the up and down-stream speeds can trip it up because its flow control is lacking).  Having said that, you should look at using a more recent version of lighttpd than 1.4.18 - version 1.4.30 is current.  However, even an uptodate version may stumble on your particular network.

Since you are in an embedded environment upgrading lighttpd may not be possible so you could also try some tricks like repeating the upstream address so that mod_proxy will "fail" over to the same server if it thinks there's an error.  You can also play with the `proxy.balance` config which takes a value of  `fair, round-robin` or `hash` - sometimes that can help.

Comment: Since using alternative proxy.balance settings didn't helped me much, I'll give v1.4.30 a try. Would nginx be a better alternative in an embedded environment though?

Comment: I haven't used nginx much but as I recall its proxying was more reliable when I compared it to lighttpd so it might better suit your purpose.